# Probability Coin and Dice fallacy?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In a coin experiment, one may toss two coins simultaneously, or one after the other. Does it make a difference if the coins are indistinguishable or distinct?
For me, if two coins are tossed simultaneously, then the sample spaces are:

Indistinguishable coins:
$$
\{\{H, H\}, \{H, T\}, \{T, T\}\}.
$$

Distinct coins:
$$
\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}
$$

Is this correct? And if a question is given like "If three coins are tossed simultaneously, what is the probability that we obtain two heads and one tail?". In this question, what is the case we should take, as nothing is mentioned about the coins?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had two coins, lightly painted blue and green so that they are *clearly distinct*, and use a mechanical device to toss them as closely as possible in time and space, wait a moment so the result can be recorded, then retrieve them for the next toss.   Thus determining the probabilities of the results through practical.

Next, without disturbing the setup in any way, we place a box of red-tinted glass over the device so that any observer cannot tell which coin is which—their distinction is hidden by colour filtration—, and then repeat the experiment again.

Would you anticipate that the fact that any observer cannot distinguish the coins during the second experiment would somehow affect the probability of the outcomes?   Or would you anticipate that being able or unable to distinguish the coins would have no such affect at all?   (Beyond, that is, being unable to distinguish between $\rm\color{green}{H}\color{blue}{T}$ and $\rm\color{blue}{H}\color{green}{T}$ when they both appear to be $\rm{HT}$.)

Comment: I got this doubt from this reference:http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/SampleSpaces.shtml . You say this this wrong?

Comment: @MaheshKumar No, it is correct; it is just not saying what you seem to think it is.  Nowhere does it suggest that the three atomic outcomes identified for the Indistinguishable Coins' sample space have identical probability measures.

Comment: It is given like "depending on the nature of the experiment, there are 3 or 4 outcomes, with the sample spaces".What does it actually mean?.Can you explain in a lucid manner with counter examples ?.I stuck  in this for last 2 days!.

Comment: @MaheshKumar It just means the same experiment can be measured in different ways; some of which include more detail than others.  Such as, we can record the results of individual coins, or we can just count the number of heads. There are 4 distinct outcomes of the first way, but can be just 3 distinct results by the second; even though the underlying mechanism generating those results is the same.$$\{(T,T),(T,H),(H,T),(H,H)\}\text{ vs. }\{0, 1, 2\}$$ A sample space is just a list of all distinct outcomes. It does not, *by itself*, say anything about how probable those outcomes may be.

Comment: "A sample space is just a list of all distinct outcomes" this is where i got the problem. As in the document "Depending on the nature of the experiment, ** there are 3 or 4 outcomes, with the sample spaces

Indistinguishable coins
  S1={{H, H}, {H, T}, {T, T}}.
 
Distinct coins
  S2={HH, HT, TH, TT}   ** ".  So by using the definition of sample space ,and finding the Cardinality ,n(S1)=3 and n(S2)=4.  **As the Cardinality differs, the probability of getting exactly 1 head deiffers .**.P(Getting exactly 1 head)=1/3 using S1 and P(Getting exactly 1 head)=2/4 using S2. Am i right? .

Answer (score 1):

The sample space is {HH},{HT},{TT} but the probability of sample {HT} is 1/2 since we can get heads on the first coin and tails on the second or vice versa, regardless of whether the two coins are tossed simultaneously or with infinitesimal time difference.

Comment: The word "Infinitesimal" Is completely redundant in this answer.

Comment: it reinforces the idea that just a small time difference on that scale will not make a difference to the probabilities, i think

Comment: But even if the coins are tossed 5 years appart, the answer is still the same.

Comment: yeh ur right, i used it because it's close to being simultaneous, easier to visualise in your mind's eye i guess

Comment: My doubt itself is that you cannot say which is first and which is second!.That is what i mean Indistinguishable.

Comment: u can't say which first or second, but you do know that there is a first and a second; you just don't know which is which

Comment: Here they distinguish both.http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/SampleSpaces.shtml